# How can I get a class by its name in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inspect

I have a module with ~100 classes and I want to get the class whose name matches a string I am supplying.

I used inspect to generate the list of the classes and names, and iterate through that, but is there another way to do it?

What I have:

```
def get_class_by_name(input_name_string):
    for (key, cls) in inspect.getmembers(my_module, inspect.isclass):
        if key == input_name_string:
            return cls
```

Comment: My only question is: why?

Comment: Can you not use `getattr(my_module, class_name)` to retrieve whatever object has the name of the class you want? Which should be the `class` object.

Comment: If there's a shared superclass, you can pull them out of its `.__subclasses__()`. It would be helpful to give some context on what you're actually trying to achieve, though.

Comment: `vars(my_module)[class_name]` would do as well.

Comment: Are you looking for isinstance() ?

Comment: You can use the [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) dict, `globals()[class_name]` (if it happens inside the same module...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use getattr on the module :

```py
import my_module

getattr(my_module, class_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary for this and the string is always the key to the class.

Here a code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "A"
    def print(self):
        print(self.name)

class B:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def print(self):
        print(self.name)

def get_class_by_name(input_name_string, dict):
    return dict[input_name_string]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_classes = {}
    my_classes["A"] = A()
    my_classes["B"] = B

    C = get_class_by_name("A", my_classes)
    C.print()

    D = get_class_by_name("B", my_classes)("Hallo")
    D.print()
```

Comment: That dict is already a built-in, called [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals). Try something like `globals()['A']` and see what happens